# custom panel between wrap panel and grid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, panel

i want a some panel between wrap panel and grid.this panel must resize children but if a child get to minimum width get it to next row(like wrap panel)
if there is no `minwidth` property for children act like grid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In it's current state it's unclear what you are asking. In fact it looks like a request to do something for you. This (Stackoverflow) is not the right platform for such requests. If you need some help, then please show us what you want to do (which you already did), what you have tried to achieve your goal and were you failed. We then can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [GridExtra](https://github.com/sourcechord/GridExtra)

There are so much details in `GridExtra`

You can define your grid column and rows and fill them with this command `ge:GridEx.AutoFillChildren="True"`

Sample code

```
<Grid ge:GridEx.ColumnDefinition="*, *"
    ge:GridEx.RowDefinition="Auto, Auto, Auto"
    ge:GridEx.AutoFillChildren="True"
    ShowGridLines="True">
    <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Age:" />
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5"/>

    <Button ge:GridEx.Area="2, 1, 1, 1"
        Margin="5" Width="60"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Content="OK" />
</Grid>
```